# Could a creature with nonhuman anatomy still have a regenerative healing factor?

Tags: super-powers, anatomy

Normally in fiction users of regenerative healing factor have human or mostly human physiology. My question is whether a creature with a nonhuman body could have a regenerative healing factor. Could, for example, an ant, elephant, tiger, bear, beetle, shark, etc. have a healing factor? My specific creature I am looking to add a regenerative healing factor to is a creature with 40 heads, 40 legs, 20 arms, and 10 chests. This creature also has tons of tusks, claws, and horns. It also has 4 mouths and its heads are shaped like triangles of the irregular type. This creature has a wildly different physiology, but could it still be able to regenerate? There are other creatures that I want to give a healing factor to, but that would be too much for this post. The healing factor works by undoing injuries at 2/3 the speed they occur at. My explanation is that the users are possessed by an evil spirit. Evil spirits can possess any physical thing, such as a plant, animal or even a bar of soap.

In short, could a creature with a nonhuman physiology still have a healing factor/regeneration, and it still be internally consistent?

Comment: How do healing factors work in your world? Is there some thing that would prevent nonhumans from regenerating. Without knowing how it works how do you expect us to be able to answer this question.

Comment: @sphennings the healing factor works by undoing injuries at 2/3 the speed they occur at. My explanation is that the users are possessed by an evil spirit. Evil spirits can possess any physical thing, such as a plant, animal or even a bar of soap.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant information to make this question answerable. If an evil spirit can possess anything then I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: We're not here to answer questions about audience reception. That's more of a writing concern than a worldbuilding one. It's also highly dependent on individual opinions which would make it unsuitable for this site.

Comment: @sphennings I meant if it would be logically consistent. That's what i mean by believable.Something that is not logically absurd, and that I could have in a world.

Comment: @sphennings I cannot have a triangle with 100 sides. It is not logically consistent, and it is impossible to draw or show on a movie. I want to know if having a nonhuman anatomy creature get shot and then heal itself is internally consistent: if it can be wrote or shown without being nonsense.

Comment: It's your world. You make the rules. So far you haven't written anything that contradicts itself, but we only have 2 paragraphs to go on. Consistency does not exist in isolation. It exists when there is conformity in how the facts of your world are applied. That's a function of how you build the rest of your world, and how you write stories set in your world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139800/discussion-between-sphennings-and-guy).

Comment: What are the reasons you have for believing that healing factors would not be viable for non-humanoids?

Comment: No. Science has proven that only humanoids have healing. Elephants, for instance, do not heal. The smallest cut that bleeds eventually kills the elephant once its large reservoir of blood is depleted. Small children learn this in kindergarten. Did your preschool teacher never tell you the story of the Elephant and the Papercut? I blame Common Core teaching fads and our failing public schools.

Comment: considering echinoderms can regrow their limbs and  internal organs from scratch, I'm gonna say yes.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why 'healing factors' would be exclusive to humanoids or that anyone should think they would be and you've given us no reason within your own world that might suggest you have an issue tied to your own built world so this question appears to be without purpose and trivial.

Comment: Healing factors of the type you are referring to are already completely fictional. Do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

## All lifeforms can regenerate

Life is a constant fight against entropy, with toxic chemicals like oxygen seeking to rend apart your flesh to form more stable compounds and your own atoms seeking to escape their bonds and form a more entropy friendly configuration. Short of things that most don't classify as alive like viruses and prions, everything alive has some degree of self regeneration which magic could amplify.

Comment: this looks like a copy and paste. Could you state in the comments where you got this info? @NepeneNep

Comment: Basic biology knowledge. I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially fantasy, so of course you can give any ability to any creature.

Besides, it's not necessary that only humanoids can regenerate. Taking real life examples, many salamander species and other amphibians can regenerate.

Comment: In fact, most humanoids IRL are pretty bad at regenerating, while things like amphibians, echinoderms, and others are pretty good at it.